# Google analytics test data

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Do you know if there is a test data-set for google analytics you can use? Basically, I want to try a new thing with our new student-worker at my work. The person is completely new to google analytics, and I wanted to set up a test environment, where the person can get comfortable with google analytics not fearing for making mistakes and begin to move over to our company's google analytics over the next couple of weeks.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the [Google Analytics Demo account](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6367342?hl=en). The data comes from the [Google Merchandise store](https://googlemerchandisestore.com/). There are some limitations to the access. For example, it is read only and you don't have API access.

Comment: Thank you! Thats what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a separate "sandbox" Google Analytics property specifically for testing. This way, any data changes won't affect your company's main property.
You can then use Google Tag Manager or Google Data Studio to create and import test data. There are also online generators that can help simulate traffic and user behavior on your test site.
As for [DataHive360](https://datahive360.com/), it's a valuable tool for extracting insights from your marketing data, but it may not be directly related to setting up a test environment in Google Analytics.